# JSON String incompletely wrapped

Tags: apex, json, wrapper-class

After deserializing a JSON response and casting it to the wrapper class, I see that in the debug logs half of the JSON is missing.

Am I deserializing the JSON incorrectly? Or am I not creating a correct data structire for the JSON?

```
public with sharing class MyController {

        public list<JSONWrapper> wrapper {get;set;}

        public void getDeserialize() {


        string jsonresponse = '[{"appList":[{"dealerID":"ABC123","dealerName":"ABC Auto Dealer",                    "reportingPeriod":"2019-05-                 18","fsitCode":"FIFS","idl":"Y","casCode":"STEONE","submissionCount":2},{"dealerID":                    "ABC123","dealerName":"ABC Auto Dealer","reportingPeriod":"2019-06-27","fsitCode":"FIFS","idl":"Y",                     "casCode":"STEONE","submissionCount":5}],"eclist":                  [{"dealerID":"XL1HX","submitUserID":"BCUSER1","bookedDate":"2019-05-22                  00:00:00.0","ecEligible":"Y","caBookedCount":1,"ecBookedCount":0},{"dealerID":"XL1HX","submitUserID":                   "BCUSER1","bookedDate":"2019-06-05 00:00:00.0","ecEligible":"Y","caBookedCount":1,"ecBookedCount":                  0}]}]';

            system.debug('json string is ' +jsonresponse);
            wrapper = (list<JSONWrapper>) JSON.deserialize(jsonresponse, list<JSONWrapper>.class);

    system.debug('This is the wrapper' +wrapper);

    }

}




public class JSONWrapper {

    public List<ApplicationList> appList{get;set;}
    public List<ElectronicContractList> eclist {get;set;}

    public class ElectronicContractList{
        public String  dealerID{get;set;}
        public String submitUserID{get;set;}
        public String bookedDate{get;set;}
        public String ecEligible{get;set;}
        public Integer caBookedCount{get;set;}
        public Integer ecBookedCount{get;set;}
    }

    public class ApplicationList {
        public String dealerID{get;set;}
        public String dealerName{get;set;}
        public String reportingPeriod{get;set;}
        public String fsitCode{get;set;}
        public String idl{get;set;}
        public String casCode{get;set;}
        public Integer submissionCount{get;set;}
    }
}


|DEBUG|This is the wrapper : 

**strong text**(JSONWrapper:[appList=
(ApplicationList:[casCode=STEONE, dealerName=ABC Auto Dealer, 
fsitCode=FIFS, idl=Y, reportingPeriod=2019-05-18, dealerID=XL1HX, 
submissionCount=2],
ApplicationList:[casCode=STEONE, dealerName=ABC Auto Dealer, 
fsitCode=FIFS, idl=Y, reportingPeriod=2019-06-27, 
dealerID=XL1HX, submission**strong text**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They recently changed debugging so they truncate long strings. You need to right click and `View Raw Log` to see the entire output.